# Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix A

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The 2x2 matrix is A=(-6 13), (-4 2)

I found the two eigen values that are $\lambda=-2+6i$ and $\lambda=-2-6i$, but I do not understand why I cannot find the eigenvectors.

Comment: Do we have to consider $(-6,13)$ as a row or column of the matrix?

Comment: Your statement of the problem is unclear. Check the mathjax tutorial for help with writing matrices.

Comment: Without any details of what you’ve tried so far, we don’t understand why you can’t find the eigenvectors, either.